# Problem using NPM Moment.js in React: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__format is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, momentjs

Edit: I've solved my problem for now using dateFns (date-fns.org) but I'd be keen to know how to use Momentjs here as well.

I've created an app using `create-react-app` and am trying to convert the current data to a string using a format.  I am getting the following error, however

> moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__format  is not a function

when I try to run this code

```
import moment from 'moment'

 const today = moment().calendar().format('DD-MM-YYY')
 const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days').calendar().format('DD-MM-YYY')
 this.setState({checkin:today,checkout:tomorrow})
```

I did some googling and found pages like https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4229, where one suggestion was to try

`import * as moment from 'moment'`

but that didn't help either.

I also tried

`import * as moment from 'moment/moment'`

which was another suggestion, but it also didn't work.

Even just calling

`moment.format('DD-MM-YYY')`

throws the same error.

My `package.json` has these dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
```

I'm at a loss here how to move forward.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: try to install the react-moment

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 const today = moment(moment().calendar()).format('DD-MM-YYY')
 const tomorrow = moment(moment().add(1, 'days').calendar()).format('DD-MM-YYY')
```

I am supposing that `.calender()` would return a `string`, if we need to parse it to a specific format we would then be needing to pass it as a *param* to another `moment` instance then apply `format` to it.